# o From XMLHTTPRequest is Undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax

So, I lifted this nice AJAX code from another site. Problem is that I such a lame JavaScript programmer that I can figure out how to get the output onto my page. My startUp() function says o is undefined. I do see the results of the php on the Firebug console.

TIA for your help.

```
var asyncRequest = function() {
  function handleReadyState(o, callback) {
    if (o && o.readyState == 4 && o.status == 200) {
      if (callback) {
        callback(o);
      }
    }
  }

  var getXHR = function() {
    var http;
    try {
      http = new XMLHttpRequest;
        getXHR = function() {
          return new XMLHttpRequest;
        };
    }
    catch(e) {
      var msxml = [
        'MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0', 
        'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', 
        'Microsoft.XMLHTTP'
      ];

      for (var i=0, len = msxml.length; i < len; ++i) {
        try {
          http = new ActiveXObject(msxml[i]);
          getXHR = function() {
            return new ActiveXObject(msxml[i]);
          };

          break;
        }

        catch(e) {}
      }
    }

    return http;

  };

  return function(method, uri, callback, postData) {
    var http = getXHR();
    http.open(method, uri, true);
    handleReadyState(http, callback);
    http.send(postData || null);

    return http;
  };

}();

asyncRequest('GET', 'voterserver.php', function(o) {
    console.log(o.responseText);
});

function startUp() {
    //alert("Here!");
    document.getElementById("user_list").innerHTML=o.responseText;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asyncRequest takes a callback function as the 3rd parameter thats the

```
function(o) {
    console.log(o.responseText);
}
```

within it

the value of o passed to that function and is not available in your startUp function.

you need to rewrite your startup as follows

```
function startUp() {
    asyncRequest(
      'GET', 
      'voterserver.php', 
      function(o) 
      {
          document.getElementById("user_list").innerHTML=o.responseText;
      });
}
```

I've set the indentation to make it clearer.

You may want too look at using one of the Javascript frameworks that makes this sort of thing alot easier and has good documentation, I use mootools but JQuery is very popular.

**UPDATE**

I tried to make a JSFIddle with thte code you put in your question and it didnt work, I've made changes to it to get it to work and its **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cn44q/)** for you to try.

Same thing with MooTools **[MooTools](http://jsfiddle.net/cPZDv/)**

Comment: Thanks much for the quick response. I've seen quite a bit about the various frame works on the net but I've been reluctant to sue one for fear of bloat. My application is pretty simple but it's very time sensitive. I'd like to have a refresh interval of 100 milliseconds maybe 250 max. Do you think one of the javascript frame works would meet that requirement?

Comment: I used the suggested modification to my code and it makes sense to do it that way. But the response is still not showing up on my page. I suspect that it's because the page is not finished loading when the script runs because I see talk about that in the frameworks sites. But as I mentioned above I'm reluctant to use a framework. So  I put a <script>startUp()</script> at the bottom of my page but that didn't work.

Comment: yes, I have pages doing 200ms interval ajax requests returning multiple images (dataurls) no problem, I've tested faster but not needed for my applications.

Comment: jsfiddle must be down tonight. I'll try your links later. I did dive into jQuery and after a couple of hours with it I have a working page. I did in 15 lines of jQuery what I could not do with 150 of my own XHR code. Guess I'm a convert.